# .NET 4.5 Async programming with report service

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have a web application (Web Forms, 4.5, C#) in which I have a reports menu. Traditionally, I have selection screens and have the user run the report and wait for it to return (i.e file or web HTML viewer). And even having it AJAX'd helps let the user knows something is occuring, but I want to move it to the next level.
I've read a lot on 4.5's async and await coding. Most has been for Windows apps, which mine is not.

I'd like to create a service and have my web form app call the service async and then have the response back on report completion occur on the same user session but on any screen that they are in. As a window prompt or something elegant.

My report technology is Active Reports 7 (but it could work for Crystal, etc).

Any good examples, links, or ideas? Thanx.

I have made a sample report async but that doesn't gain me much since it is basically one operation (Dataset building) that takes the time up.

I can create a WCF or SOAP web service but how do I handle the orignal thread/sesion return to the UI?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but (as I explain on my blog) [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

From your description, it sounds like SignalR may be able to do something similar to what you want.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to create the Async operation on the data call for the report, then allow the UI to continue. The user would get a message telling them that their report is "queued up" so to speak. Then since this is Ajax'd I could have an area in the master page header "polling" the report queue and display the report link when it shows up. Thoughts?

Comment: That's one solution. I prefer SignalR/WebSockets over polling, if you have the option. However, you don't want to keep your reports in-memory on the server side; [I explain why this is a bad idea on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html). Instead, you want a real queue with a backend independent from ASP.NET.